# ovirt 3.6 to ovirt 4.2 Migration

Tags: backup, migration, ovirt

We are running Ovirt3.6 version in our prod, we want to upgrade to 3.6 to
4.2.

At present we have 2 (hyp A & hyp B)physical host ovirt 3.6 is running with self hosted engine with data domain and iso one cluster and data center.
What we were thing do this migration in following fashion.

**Plan A.**

1. Attach export domain present infra.
2. Take backup all of running vm as export.
3. Detach export domain
4. Detach hyp B from cluster and data center
5. Install fresh ovirt 4.2 iso on hyp B
6. Install self hosted engine
7. Attach Data Domain
8. Attach Export Domain which was use in ovirt 3.8
9. Import all vm's from there to new ovirt 4.2
10. Once all the vm's got up and running poweroff hyp A
11. Install fresh ovirt 4.2 iso on hyp A and attach cluster.

**Plan B.**

1. Attach export domain present infra.
2. Take backup all of running vm as export.
3. Detach export domain
4. Detach hyp B from cluster and data center
5. Install fresh ovirt 4.2 iso on hyp B
6. Install self hosted engine
7. Attach Data Domain
8. Export from ovirt 3.8 to ovirt 4.2
9. Once all the vm's got up and running poweroff hyp A
10. Install fresh ovirt 4.2 iso on hyp A and attach cluster.

Thank a ton in advance we may be wrong with above step help us to win this
migration.

Regards
Techieim

Answer (score 0):

**Plan B** won't work since Data Domain is still attached to oVirt 3.6.

For **Plan A** I assume you are providing two additional storage units:

1. One storage unit for the new **hosted_storage** Domain (the data domain for the Self Hosted Engine)
2. One storage for the new Data Domain (the one for VMs)

That being said, both plans fails to provide business continuity since they need VMs to be powered off and run on the new environment.

I strongly suggest you to go through the whole update process from oVirt 3.6 to 4.0, then from 4.0 to 4.1 and finally from 4.1 to 4.2. The documentation on ovirt.org is not fully updated to 4.2 yet but you can peek at the [official Red Hat Virtualization documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/).

Chapter 6.2 of [RHV 4.2 Self-Hosted Engine Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.2/html/self-hosted_engine_guide/upgrading_a_rhev-h_she_to_rhvh) clearly describes the aforementioned process. Just keep in mind the following analogies:

- Host or RHVH (RHEV-H till 3.6) → oVirt Node
- Manager or RHVM (RHEV-M till 3.6) → oVirt Engine